# Find out which test classes hit a particular class

Tags: apex, unit-test, class

Does Salesforce have a functionality that lets you identify which test classes (and possibly which of those tests) cover a particular Apex class?

I know that if you run a test class then you see which classes that test class covers but I would like the reverse if possible.

Comment: Related [How to identify classes covered in test class in spring 13 release?](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/q/7374/102)

Answer (score 8):

Are you looking for something like this?

Developer **Console > File > Open > 'Select class'**, top left corner says which tests are covering the specific class

[image: Developer console]

Comment: I guess if no classes appear there... then there are no tests for the class, right?